# Azure Node.js querystring return nothing when attempting to stringify object

Tags: android, node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am attempting to stringify the Shared Access query string url. However it returns nothing. Below is the code:

```
var table = module.exports = require('azure-mobile-apps').table();
var azure = require('azure');
var qs = require('querystring');
var logger = require('azure-mobile-apps/src/logger');

// table.read(function (context) {
//     return context.execute();
// });

 // table.read.use(customMiddleware, table.operation);

 table.insert(function (context) {
// Get storage account settings from app settings. 
var accountName = 'xxx';
var accountKey = 'xxx';
var host = accountName + '.blob.core.windows.net';

if ((typeof context.item.containerName !== "undefined") && (
context.item.containerName !== null)) {
    // Set the BLOB store container name on the item, which must be lowercase.
    context.item.containerName = context.item.containerName.toLowerCase();

    // If it does not already exist, create the container 
    // with public read access for blobs.        
    var blobService = azure.createBlobService(accountName, accountKey, host);
    blobService.createContainerIfNotExists(context.item.containerName, {
        publicAccessLevel: 'blob'
    }, function(error) {
        if (!error) {

            // Provide write access to the container for the next 5 mins.        
            var sharedAccessPolicy = {
                AccessPolicy: {
                    Permissions: azure.Constants.BlobConstants.SharedAccessPermissions.WRITE,
                    Expiry: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 5 * 60 * 1000)
                }
            };

            // Generate the upload URL with SAS for the new image.
            var sasQueryUrl = 
            blobService.generateSharedAccessSignature(context.item.containerName, 
            context.item.resourceName, sharedAccessPolicy);

            // Set the query string.
            context.item.sasQueryString = qs.stringify(sasQueryUrl.queryString);

            // Set the full path on the new new item, 
            // which is used for data binding on the client. 
            context.item.imageUri = sasQueryUrl.baseUrl + sasQueryUrl.path;
            logger.debug('h); e); l); l); o)'); 
            logger.debug(sasQueryUrl);
            logger.debug(context.item.sasQueryString);
        } else {
            console.error(error);
            logger.error(error);                           
        }
        return context.execute();
    });
} else {
    return context.execute();
}
```

});

The output of the logger returns:

```
2016-08-16T13:50:24.820Z - debug: h); e); l); l); o)

2016-08-16T13:50:24.836Z - debug: se=2016-08-16T13%3A55%3A24Z&sp=w&sv=2015-   04-05&sr=b&sig=euf53CcO8SDqJowFBFiKPgRTpVt21HmRUlppN9piatY%3D

2016-08-16T13:50:24.852Z - debug:
```

As you can see the problem occures when **se=2016-08-16T13%3A55%3A24Z&sp=w&sv=2015-04-05&sr=b&sig=euf53CcO8SDqJowFBFiKPgRTpVt21HmRUlppN9piatY%3D** unable to return queryString, baseUrl and path.

I tried to install npm querystring inside the console and attempt to run it but still does not work. Here is the tutorial I have referenced.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-upload-data-blob-storage/

Too bad the newer version of the portal is not compatible with the tutorial, hence I tried to port the code to newer one.

Thank you.

Comment: You should probably be doing a SAS token generation as a custom API.  See https://shellmonger.com/2016/05/30/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-27-file-handling-v1/ for info on file upload.  You should be able to integrate with the Android tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

The sample in the URL you linked is out of date for the current version of the azure package. The `blobService.generateSharedAccessSignature` method now returns the querystring directly, rather than an object containing querystring, baseUrl and path properties. You should not need to use the `querystring.stringify` method at all.